# C AndroidAnnotation не работают выпадающие списки: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 19820: Landroid/widget/Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

В андроиде (minSdkVersion 17, targetSdkVersion 25, compileSdkVersion 25) перестали работать Spinner - выпадающие списки. Произошло это сразу после начала пользования AndroidAnnotation. В logcat это выглядит так:

```
10-26 14:33:16.109 10056-10060/com.sb.myapp D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 174K, 11% free 2934K/3292K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 2ms
10-26 14:33:16.113 10056-10056/com.sb.myapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.Spinner.getPopupContext, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.getPopupContext
10-26 14:33:16.113 10056-10056/com.sb.myapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 19811: Landroid/widget/Spinner;.getPopupContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
10-26 14:33:16.113 10056-10056/com.sb.myapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
10-26 14:33:16.113 10056-10056/com.sb.myapp I/ListPopupWindow: Could not find method setEpicenterBounds(Rect) on PopupWindow. Oh well.
10-26 14:33:16.113 10056-10056/com.sb.myapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatPopupWindow.showAsDropDown
10-26 14:33:16.113 10056-10056/com.sb.myapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 19722: Landroid/widget/PopupWindow;.showAsDropDown (Landroid/view/View;III)V
10-26 14:33:16.113 10056-10056/com.sb.myapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000d
10-26 14:33:16.121 10056-10056/com.sb.myapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.View.<init>, referenced from method android.support.constraint.Guideline.<init>
10-26 14:33:16.121 10056-10056/com.sb.myapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 18701: Landroid/view/View;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;II)V
10-26 14:33:16.121 10056-10056/com.sb.myapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
10-26 14:33:16.125 10056-10056/com.sb.myapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.<init>
10-26 14:33:16.125 10056-10056/com.sb.myapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 2308 (Landroid/widget/ThemedSpinnerAdapter;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter;
10-26 14:33:16.125 10056-10056/com.sb.myapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x0014
```

Основной месседж здесь это:

```
Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter'
```

Кроме того, не уверен, что это связано - но перестало работать `setVisibility(View.GONE)` при onCreate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. Это касается только случая, когда вы перешли на AndroidAnnotations.

В общем, я раньше в методе `onCreate()` получал View через `findViewById(R.id...)` и работал с ним. А теперь они в `onCreate()` ещё null. Они будут забиндены позже, и чтобы отловить этот момент, я использовал метод с аннотацией `@AfterViews`. Этот метод будет исполнен сразу после того, как все Views были забиндены, и теперь являются соответствующими объектами.